# Is there a way retrieve piece of information of a control (linearlayout) created in dynamic way?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm working on an android project which allow the user to fill a form.

The picture below descripts my differents layouts for the form.
[image: This is my form]

The black layout (LinearMain) is my principal linear layout.
The green one (LinearForm) descripts the rows of the form.

> LinearMain.addView(LinearForm);

The blue one (LinearDescription) contains the description the row the form to fill in.

> LinearForm.addView(LinearDescription);

And the gray linear layout descripts my controls. The control can be an EditText, a button or a CheckBox.

> For example LinearForm.addView(LinearButton)

After filling in the form I want to retrieve the text in the EditText, Know if the CheckBox is Checked or not.
I already try to use an ArrayList (example ArrayList) but it's not very helpful.

Is there another way to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)` is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29)

you can create a for loop to go through `LinearLayout`'s children, check if corresponding children is `instanceof CheckBox` and get the value `((CheckBox) getChildAt(i)).isChecked()`

Sample code:

```
LinearLayout ll;

for ( int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
    View child = ll.getChildAt(i);
    if ( child instanceof CheckBox ) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) child).isChecked();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @m1shk4. Your thread sounds good but the instanciation of the checkbox for example catch this exception : android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox

Comment: thanks @m1shk4 it works fine now. I test the Child (0) of the gray linear layout.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't know exactly with view you are to deal with it is important here to use instance of to avoid exceptions

`ViewGroup` is an abstract class that extends all ViewGroups, LinearLayout for instance is a ViewGroup.

```
 if(ViewGroup.getChildAt(int) instanceof Checkbox){

//do sommethng here
}else if(ViewGroup.getChildAt(int) instanceof Button){

//do sommethng here
}else if(ViewGroup.getChildAt(int) instanceof TextView){

//do sommethng here
}else if(ViewGroup.getChildAt(int) instanceof EditText){

//do sommethng here
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by your ViewGroup. Is that the class from android.view or my linearLayout?

Comment: @zim ViewGroup is an abstract class that extends all ViewGroups, LinearLayout for instance is a ViewGroup.

Comment: @zim (gray linear layout) is what i call here viewGroup

Answer (score 1):

You could set id to your View, never mind what view it is by: `LinearButton.setId();`
and then get the text by `using findViewById(R.id.chosenId).getText().toString();`
for `EditText` or `findViewById(R.id.chosenId).isChecked();` for `CheckBox`.

another way is to save your view in a arrayList of views and to access them using this array.

Answer (score 0):

Have u created the layout in `xml` and set the id of each of the view ?
If yes then all u need to just create the object of the `EditText` using `findViewById(R.id.edittext)` and then use `getText()` method of the `EditText` to get the text from the `EditText`. And for `CheckBox` you can use `findViewById(R.id.chosenId).isChecked()`.