# getchild of a view on a click event

Tags: android, view, get-childitem

Sorry by my english.. this is google traductor

I create (java) for example 10 LLseccion.

Each LLseccionhas multiple objects inside (imageview and 2 textview)

i want read the first textview of a layout clicked

```
        LinearLayout LLseccion = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        LLseccion.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LLseccion.setId(i);
        LLseccion.setClickable(true);

        LLseccion.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });



                TextView tvBIG=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tvBIG.setText("i want read this");
                tvBIG.setTypeface(FontNormal);
                tvBIG.setTextSize(bigSize);
                tvBIG.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GREEN));
                tvBIG.setSingleLine(true);
                LLseccion.addView(tvBIG);

                    TextView tvSMALL=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    tvSMALL.setText("other text");
                    tvSMALL.setTypeface(FontNormal);
                    tvSMALL.setTextSize(smallSize);
                    tvSMALL.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GREEN));
                    tvSMALL.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
                    tvSMALL.setSingleLine(true);
                    LLseccion.addView(tvSMALL);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337094/is-there-a-way-retrieve-piece-of-information-of-a-control-linearlayout-created Hope this will help you.